# Executing a python script from Golang with arguments

Tags: go

I am trying to execute a python script ( which is used for accessing remote machines and run commands ) from Golang, it errors with "exit status 2"

```
out, err := exec.Command("/usr/local/opt/bin/python3.7", "/users/test.py -i 12.13.14.15 --cmd \"uptime && date\"").Output()


if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("%s", err)
} else {
    fmt.Println("Command Successfully Executed")
    output := string(out[:])
    fmt.Println(output)
}
```

Output

```
exit status 2
```

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing a single argument to the executable containing everything. Instead, you have to pass each argument separately:

```
out, err := exec.Command("/usr/local/opt/bin/python3.7", "/users/test.py", "-i", "12.13.14.15", "--cmd", "uptime && date").Output()
```